# Lie bracket returning input vecor

Tags: lie-algebras

For a non-abelian Lie algebra $(\mathfrak{g},[\cdot,\cdot])$, given $X\in\mathfrak{g}$, when is it possible to find $Y\in\mathfrak{g}$ such that  $[X, Y]=X$? How about finding $Z\in\mathfrak{g}$ such that $[[X,Y],Z]=[X,Y]$?

Comment: reworded my question

Comment: have you learned about the $\mathrm{ad}$- representation of an algebra?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the Lie algebra is nilpotent, then there is no such $Y$, because by Engel's Theorem all adjoint operators $ad(Y)$ are nilpotent. If $[X,Y]=X$, then $ad(Y)X=[Y,X]=-X$, so that $ad(Y)$ has an eigenvalue different from zero, a contradiction. The same holds for $[[X,Y],Z]=[X,Y]$ considering $ad(Z)$. 
In other words, the $2$-dimensional non-abelian Lie algebra $L$ of dimension $2$, with brackets $[X,Y]=X$, is solvable, non-nilpotent. Hence it cannot be a subalgebra of a nilpotent Lie algebra.

For non-nilpotent Lie algebras the question is harder to answer. For example, a reductive Lie algebra contains no non-abelian Lie subalgebra of dimension $2$ if it is anisotropic, i.e., where all $ad(x)$ are semisimple.